# duplicate namespace and function names in different assemblies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll, c#-4.0, naming

I have a project in visual studio 2010 and I'm using C# with .NetFramework 4.0. Is there a way of having two references to two dlls which have the same name, namespace and function names, but different internal implementation/logic?

Comment: Search SO for "extern alias".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hans pointed out, you'd need to use aliases. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ansonh/archive/2006/09/27/774692.aspx) explains this in better detail.